# Find all points on a surface which have a tangent plane parallel to given plane - is my method correct?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The question given is to find all points on the surface given by $x^3 - y^3 - 2xy - z = 0$ which have a tangent plane which is parallel to $6x - 6y - z = 0$.

So, I found the two gradient vectors (which we defined as $f_{x}e_{1} + f_{y}e_{2} + f_{z}e_{3}$) and said that one must be a scalar multiple of the other in order to be parallel. Then, as $f_{x} = 6k$ and $f_{y} = -6k$, I was able to set $f_{x} = -f_{y}$ and by cancelling I solved to get $y = x - \frac{2}{3}$ and worked out that all points of the form $(x, x - \frac{2}{3}, z)$ appear to satisfy the conditions given. Then I substituted this into the surface equation to get a value for $z$ which simplified nicely to $\frac{8}{27}$. So, all points of the form $(x,x - \frac{2}{3}, \frac{8}{27})$ is the final answer I got.  I have tried a couple of values for $x$ and the gradient vector does work out to be a scalar multiple of the plane's gradient.

I would really appreciate if somebody could quickly work out the answer and verify if I have found the correct answer, or tell me if I am doing it wrong?

Thanks! Helen

Comment: It doesn't make sense for the normal vectors to be vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ as you assume when you use $f_xe_1+f_ye_2$. You can't forget about the $z$-component, meaning that you should take the gradient of the three-variable function $f(x,y,z)=x^2-y^3-2xy-z$ of which your surface is a level surface, and similarly for the given plane. (In other words, you can't move the $z$ term to the right as you did.) The resulting gradients should be parallel yes, but by comparing the $z$-coordinates you can conclude that they must be equal, as the solution you commented on below suggests.

Comment: When I did the question using all three components, I got the same end result, $(x,x - \frac{2}{3}, \frac{8}{27} )$

Comment: I have edited my question to show what I did with three variables.

Comment: Using only $f_x=-f_y$ isn't enough since you're ignoring that you have actual values for each of these, 6 for the first and -6 for the second. (Again, $k$ must be $1$ as you can determine by looking at the $z$-components of the gradients.) Your solution gives points for which $f_x=-f_y$ but which don't satisfy $f_x = 6$ and $f_y = -6$ as required. Once you have $y=x-\frac23$ you can then use $f_x=6$ for solve for $x$ to narrow down your values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now!

Comment: Also, when coming up with $y=x-\frac23$ it seems you divided by $x+y$ at some point, meaning that doing this ignores possible points for which $x+y=0$. So, you should consider these points separately at the end, meaning use $y=-x$ and $f_x=6$ to find precise points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the surface
$$z = f(x,y) = {x^3} - {y^3} - 2xy$$
we have a parametrization:
$$\phi (x,y) = (x,y,{x^3} - {y^3} - 2xy)$$
with partials:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {\partial _x}\phi  = \left( {1,0,3{x^2} - 2y} \right) \hfill \\
  {\partial _y}\phi  = \left( {0,1, - 3{y^2} - 2x} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
and an normal vector:
$${\partial _x}\phi  \times {\partial _y}\phi  = \left( {2y - 3{x^2},2x + 3{y^2},1} \right)$$
Normal vector from the plane and normal vector must be parallel,
so we may set:
$$\left( {2y - 3{x^2},2x + 3{y^2},1} \right) = \left( { - 6,6,1} \right)$$
This leads to the system:
$$\begin{gathered}
  2y - 3{x^2} =  - 6 \hfill \\
  2x + 3{y^2} = 6 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
with four solutions:
$$\begin{gathered}
  (x,y) = \left( {\frac{1}{3} - \sqrt {\frac{5}{3}} , - \frac{1}{3} - \sqrt {\frac{5}{3}} } \right) \hfill \\
  (x,y) = \left( {\frac{1}{3} + \sqrt {\frac{5}{3}} , - \frac{1}{3} + \sqrt {\frac{5}{3}} } \right) \hfill \\
  (x,y) = \left( {\frac{1}{3}\left( { - 1 - \sqrt {19} } \right),\frac{1}{3}\left( {1 + \sqrt {19} } \right)} \right) \hfill \\
  (x,y) = \left( {\frac{1}{3}\left( { - 1 + \sqrt {19} } \right),\frac{1}{3}\left( {1 - \sqrt {19} } \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$

Answer (score 0):

$(3x^2-2y,-3y^2-2x,-1)=(6,-6,-1)$, since their normals must also be parallel as well. This will give $(x+y)(3(x-y)-2)=0$ solving this you can get the result.

Comment: Aren't the normal vectors and gradient vectors the same? Also, if they are parallel, I believe they must be scalar multiples of eachother, not equal, is this correct?

Comment: @HelenByrne, see my comment to your original question.